# how can I have the following bibliography display?

Tags: bibliographies, authorindex

I am using aphalike.bst for my bibliography, which will give me this style:

**Takemoto, B. K., Olszyk, D. M., Johnson, A. G., and Parada, C. R. .1988. Yield responses of field-grown crops to acidic fog and ambient ozone. Journal of Environmental Quality, 17(2):192-197.**

but I need the the following

**Takemoto, B. K., Olszyk, D. M., Johnson, A. G., and C. R.,Parada. 1988. Yield responses of field-grown crops to acidic fog and ambient ozone. Journal of Environmental Quality, 17(2):192-197.**

The difference is that the last author shown as Initials, Lastname.

I think change the code in the bst file will make it.

```
> FUNCTION {format.names} { 's :=   #1 'nameptr :=   s num.names$
> 'numnames :=   numnames 'namesleft :=
>     { namesleft #0 > }
>     { s nameptr "{vv~}{ll}{, jj}{, f.}" format.name$ 't :=   % last name first
>       nameptr #1 >    { namesleft #1 >
>       { ", " * t * }
>       { numnames #2 >         { "," * }       'skip$
>         if$
>         t "others" =      { " et~al." * }         { " and " * t * }
>         if$
>       }     if$   }   't
>       if$
>       nameptr #1 + 'nameptr :=
>       namesleft #1 - 'namesleft :=
>     }   while$ }
```

But I am not sure how to do that. Hope someone can help. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Does the entire typeset bibliographic entry need to be rendered in **bold**? Please advise.

Comment: Please provide more information about your objectives for formatting the `author` field. E.g., should the `FirstInitials.,Surname` rule apply if there's just one author? Two authors? Three or more authors? Please also confirm that there should be no space between the comma and the final author's surname. (Speaking for myself, obviously, I can't help but recoil from such a formatting style.)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't make it clear. I just used bold to make them easier to look at. The formatting need be like this:  Author 1 to n:'Initials., Surname', then last author: 'Surname, Initalls.' If only one author, just use 'Initials., Surname'

Comment: This description is the almost exact opposite of what you stated in the posting itself. Which version applies?

Comment: I found a way using latex makebst to work on it now. It is AGU style. Got some type errors while I replied you. Thank you very much.

Comment: I used apsr.bst, modified it by removing the URL, and changing the italic of Journal names. It worked now. Thank you!

Comment: Well, then please write an self answer.